# Scaling image using CSS only if the image is wider than the page

Tags: css

I'm putting together an "online help" system, which will display HTML content in a fairly narrow window. I'd like to display images in this window, but have them scaled to fit the width. However, I only want to horizontally scale the image down if the image is wider than the page - in other words, I never want to *stretch* the image to fit, only shrink it.

I've tried

```
.img {width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

... which just scales every image to the page width (i.e. stretches as well as shrinks)

```
.img {max-width: 100%; height: auto}
```

... which doesn't appear to do anything.

Is there any (CSS-only - I'm afraid jQuery isn't an option) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/DGNjW/ , resize result frame and see.

I used image size 1920x1080 px. And do not add width and height value inside html img tag. This css will resize proportionally. (including IE 7)

## HTML

```
<img src="http://www.wallhoster.com/wp-content/uploads/Best-Nature-Full-HD-Wallpapers31.jpg">
```

## CSS

```
img {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Comment: And it was only by playing around with your Fiddle I spotted the problem - max-width doesn't work (correctly?) in IE8, which is what I've been using in my dev environment. In IE9+, Chrome etc max-width does what it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

to scale down some specific image use class name of the image for example

```
.yourclass img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS properties should work, but probably there is a mistake in your CSS selector, please note that `.img` will select every DOM element with the `img` class; no "img" tag will be selected. By the way I was looking at a solution and found that the following looks enough to get the job done.

```
img { max-width: 100%; }
```

where the selector is `img` without the dot.